# schengen visa duration on stay is less than visa validity

Tags: visas, schengen

Hi got my schengen visa for 3 weeks validity but duration of stay shows 10 days, how long i can stay 10 days or 3 weeks please help

Comment: You can stay for ten days, and each of those ten days must be during the visa's period of validity.